# Hiri email client issue not sync

Tags: ubuntu, exchange

I configured Hiri with our Exhange acocount.

After some sync well done, it starts to have an issue and it fails everytime to sync and send emails. The only info I have about the error is the hiri message "Smothing went wrong" but nothing more. If I delete th eacocunt and the readd again, it start to work properly, but another time after some syncs the issue comes out again.

Having a look at the log this kind of issue comes out everytime

```
[Synchronizer MainThread] ERROR    2019-01-15 10:52:53,199   hiri.sync.runner - ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(2105 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(2105 bytes read))
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 572, in _update_chunk_length
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: b':RoutingType>MailboxXXX, YYYxxx.yyy@abc.comSMTP

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 331, in _error_catcher
  File "site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 637, in read_chunked
  File "site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 576, in _update_chunk_length
http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(2105 bytes read)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/requests/models.py", line 749, in generate
  File "site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 461, in stream
  File "site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 665, in read_chunked
  File "contextlib.py", line 77, in **exit**
  File "site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 349, in _error_catcher
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(2105 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(2105 bytes read))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hiri/sync/runner.py", line 70, in run
  File "hiri/sync/core.py", line 87, in check_mail
  File "hiri/sync/events.py", line 58, in sync_new_events
  File "hiri/sync/events.py", line 136, in _subscribe
  File "hiri/sync/core.py", line 107, in sync_hierarchy_and_all_folders
  File "hiri/sync/core.py", line 137, in _sync_all_folders
  File "hiri/sync/base.py", line 23, in wrapper
  File "hiri/sync/folders.py", line 38, in sync_folder_items
  File "hiri/sync/folders.py", line 42, in _sync_changes
  File "hiri/sync/base.py", line 71, in _get_all_items
  File "hiri/sync/base.py", line 88, in _get_items
  File "hiri/ews/wrapper.py", line 415, in get_items_extended
  File "hiri/ews/wrapper.py", line 1213, in _call_ews
  File "hiri/ews/utils.py", line 49, in wrapper
  File "hiri/ews/wrapper.py", line 1239, in _send_xml_request
  File "hiri/ews/client.py", line 239, in wrap_and_send
  File "site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 559, in post
  File "site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 512, in request
  File "site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 662, in send
  File "site-packages/requests/models.py", line 827, in content
  File "site-packages/requests/models.py", line 752, in generate
requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(2105 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(2105 bytes read))

Comment: What is the size of your inbox? How many months have you asked Hiri to sync? Have you asked logs to the Exchange maintainers? Hiri is paid and they have been responsive in all the tickets I wrote, have you involved them? PS I would guess communications issues.

Comment: Thanks you for the comment, I'm using the default sync configuration, after that I see in the log an exception as Protocol Error. How can involve Hiri team to support about my issue? Last but not least, I can use Outlook with no problems, just Hiri can't work propoerly on my inbox